# Create incremental files based on range

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I know this is probably something simple, but I've been trying to learn this for hours and I'm frustrated. I have the below script, and I'm trying to figure out how to create a new json file for each itemid retrieved.

```
from battlemuffin.clients.warcraft_client import WarcraftClient
import json

idrange = range(1, 500, 1)
filename = idrange . '.json'

response = WarcraftClient.get_item(idrange)
client = WarcraftClient('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET')
for idrange in idrange:
    response = client.get_item(idrange)
    with open(filename, 'w') as write_file:
        json.dump(response, write_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: Use an f-string: `with open(f"{idrange}.json", 'w') as write_file:`

Answer (score 0):

create filename variable in your for loop like this:

```
from battlemuffin.clients.warcraft_client import WarcraftClient
import json

idrange = range(1, 500, 1)

response = WarcraftClient.get_item(idrange)
client = WarcraftClient('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET')
for id in idrange:
    filename = '%s.json' % id
    response = client.get_item(id)
    with open(filename, 'w') as write_file:
        json.dump(response, write_file, indent=4)
```